# parse or convert HL7 message to HTML page

Tags: .net, html, xml, xslt, hl7

Given I have a HL7 message V 2.x or v3.x and I need to transform it to pretty HTML page to display its contents in reading mode.

is there an XSLT template (or library) that can help ?

is there a .NET library that can do that ?

here is a sample HL7 message:

```
MSH|^~\&|NES|NINTENDO|TESTSYSTEM|TESTFACILITY|20010101000000||ADT^A04|Q123456789T123456789X123456|P|2.3
EVN|A04|20010101000000|||^KOOPA^BOWSER^^^^^^^CURRENT
PID|1||123456789|0123456789^AA^^JP|BROS^MARIO^^^^||19850101000000|M|||123 FAKE STREET^MARIO \T\ LUIGI BROS PLACE^TOADSTOOL KINGDOM^NES^A1B2C3^JP^HOME^^1234|1234|(555)555-0123^HOME^JP:1234567|||S|MSH|12345678|||||||0|||||N
NK1|1|PEACH^PRINCESS^^^^|SO|ANOTHER CASTLE^^TOADSTOOL KINGDOM^NES^^JP|(123)555-1234|(123)555-2345|NOK|||||||||||||
NK1|2|TOADSTOOL^PRINCESS^^^^|SO|YET ANOTHER CASTLE^^TOADSTOOL KINGDOM^NES^^JP|(123)555-3456|(123)555-4567|EMC|||||||||||||
PV1|1|O|ABCD^EFGH^|||^^|123456^DINO^YOSHI^^^^^^MSRM^CURRENT^^^NEIGHBOURHOOD DR NBR^|^DOG^DUCKHUNT^^^^^^^CURRENT||CRD|||||||123456^DINO^YOSHI^^^^^^MSRM^CURRENT^^^NEIGHBOURHOOD DR NBR^|AO|0123456789|1|||||||||||||||||||MSH||A|||20010101000000
```

Comment: Please list a sample HL7 message or link the schema. Also what version of XSLT: 1.0? or 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is create a data structure out of this message (you can use NHAPI for that), and then serialize this structure into an JSON. You can then use something simple like a mustache.js template to create an HTML page w/ embedded HL7 tags:

```
<b>Results</b>: <li>{{OBX-5-10}}
```

Comment: That could be an answer unless there is something out of the box to format that HL7. the problem here is Overhead processing, since it will require parsing the whole thing and serialising it is gonna take some processing.

Comment: @CodeGuru it's minimal overhead. my company processes thousands of hl7 messages this way. If you feel like it's too much, you can just process each message once and store a cached JSON/XML representation of the message for future access. I believe there might be already-existing tools to do this. This route is advantageous because it allows you to expose the templates to people w/ out source code access, so even site admins can edit the reports to suit them.